# variable size buffer simulink

Tags: variables, size, buffer, simulink

I'm receiving variable sized data in each simulation step in `simulink`. However I need to wait a certain amount of simulation steps before I received the whole data package and therefore I need some kind of variable sized buffer. I have no information about the total amount of data, which I'm going to receive. The only information I got, is the amount of simulation step, that I have to wait until I received the whole data.

I've tried to implement it via a `matlab function block` and several `delay blocks` that delay the output data of the `matlab function block` for one simulation step. but always failing at the variable size constraints (because the delay blocks doesn't support it) and I neither found any `buffer block` that supports the functionality, that I need here.

Hope, you can help me out!

Comment: Do you want the output to only update when a full buffer is available (i.e. at the rate that you know that you have to wait for all data to arrive), or do you want it to dynamically get bigger at the same rate as the arriving packets?

Comment: I want to wait e.g. 4 simulation step and then take all the received data and do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know your input and output sample rates, I'd suggest writing a c-mex S-function.

It wouldn't be trivial, but you can

1. set the input and output ports to have different sample rates
2. set the input and output ports to have variable signal length
3. store a pointer to a std::vector<...> class in the P work vector
4. the std::vector<...> gives you the ability to increase its size as new input data arrives, and be emptied when the data is posted to the output.

**Update based on comments:**

For code generation you need to specify an upper bound for the size of the buffer, which makes a MATLAB Function block suitable.
Specify the maximum size of the buffer, and keep track of how much f it has been filled using an internal persistent variable.

But the only way to have a block with a different sample rate at its input and its output is to write an S-Function. For the MATLAB Function approach I can think of two approaches,

a) write the code so that it has an internal buffer that fills and only updates the output when the buffer becomes full.
Of course the output sample rate will be the same as the input sample rate, but the data will only change when you specify that it should.

b) have two outputs, one being the buffer, and one being an "I've just become full" logical signal.  Then follow the block by a Triggered Subsystem that feeds the buffer straight through it, and is rising edge triggered by the logical signal.  The output of the Triggered Subsystem will then only update at the steps when the buffer becomes full.

Comment: ok thanks so far. I dont know if I can go this way, because the generated code of the simulink model will be used by an embedded system. Do you got maybe any other idea, how i can solve this?

Comment: You didn't mention code generation in your original posting.  Simulink Coder needs to know the max size of the output array to be able to generate code, so you're going to have to make a guess/estimate for the max size so that the generated code will always allocate enough memory (at compile time) for the output.  Knowing that you have to do that makes the buffer easier to create, because you can now write a MATLAB Function block with the max memory allocated and just fill it as new data arrives.  Use a persistent variable to keep track of the next element to fill when new data arrives.

Comment: I've already tried something in this way. But I do not know how I can set up the MATLAB Function Block to wait a certain amount of steps and fill up the output variable with the new incoming data.

Comment: I've added a couple more suggestions to the answer.

Comment: thanks so far.. I thought about many of those possibilities, but my main problem is: how can I save the incoming data in an internal buffer at the matlab function block, as long as it has to be contained?

Comment: What do you mean "as long as it has to be contained"?

Comment: sorry, probably the wrong word for this context :)

I mean, somehow I have to store the variable size data within the matlab function as long as some sort of counter variable (which stands for the amount of simulation steps) tells me, that I've received all packages of data. and right now I dont know how to store the new incoming data.

Comment: You have (at least) 2 persistent variables in the code: the first is the buffer; the second is an index into the buffer (which would be either the last index written to, or the next index to be written to).  The index variable would get reset each time the buffer is full, so that it can start inserted the next set of data at the first entry of the buffer.

Comment: thanks phil, you really helped me .. I didnt get that I can declare a variable as `persisent` and therefore I didnt get your proposed solution :). Everythings works fine now!